# How do I make this hover effect (hover 1 button to change an element's ID then when hovered-out it changes back to it's original ID?) [jquery,css3]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a paragraph that initially has an ID of : #main

and i have a button : #button1

so what i want to happen is, when i hover around the button i want to change the paragraph's ID into : #intro

(which has CSS3 style)

and when i hover out the button it should change the paragraph's ID into: #outro

(which has also CSS3 Style)

which I did like this:

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#button1").hover(function(){
        $("#main").attr("id","intro");
    },function(){
        $("#intro").attr("id","outro");
    });  
});
```

css

```
#main{
    color:red;
}
#intro{
    -webkit-animation: recolor .5s;
    color:blue; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes recolor {
    from{
        color:red;
    }
    to{
        color:blue;
    }
}
#outro{
    -webkit-animation: recolorout .5s;
    color:red;  
}
@-webkit-keyframes recolorout {
    from{
        color:blue;
    }
    to{
        color:red;
    }
}
```

This is working, the problem is I can only do this once. I know because i did not change it back to #main

but where do it put this one :

```
$("#outro").attr("id","main");
```

so that it would change the paragraph back to its initial state after the hovering process?

or is there other solution? thanks in advance

[**This is the js fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/twish/7eBCS/)

Comment: don't change ID. use class instead.

Comment: i already tried, i have the same problem with addClass() and removeClass() , how do i do it?

Comment: jQuery's [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) ? *ironic mode off*

Comment: there is no hover function in javascript, use mouseenter / mouseleave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this fiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/chantastic/rGc7h/1/

## Modifications through classes

Changing the id is going to make it very difficult to get back to your original state, without keeping it somewhere in your JavaScript.  Your best bet is going to be adding modifying classes to you stylesheet:

```
#main { /* base styles */ }
#main.intro { /* intro overrides */ }
#main.outro { /* outro overrides */ }
```

With these in place, you can use `.addClass()` to add the right class for the right event.

```
$('#button1').mouseenter(function () {
  $('#main').addClass('intro');
});
```

## Don't forget to remove old classes!

If you only do the above, you'll add that class will stay there forever.  This isn't what you want.  You need '.intro' to be removed so that you can add '.outro' and have those styles take over.

```
$('#button1').mouseenter(function () {
  $('#main')revomeClass().addClass('intro');
});
```

An empty `.removeClass()` will remove **ALL** classes.  So be aware of that.  In this case, it is exactly what we want.

## Using `.mouseenter`/`.mouseleave` events instead of `.hover`

This is a personal preference.  I find it easier to read and understand later. Behind the scenes, jQuery converts `.hover()` to the `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave` events.

This is the final result:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $main    = $('#main')
  $button1 = $('#button1')

  $button1.mouseenter(function () {
    $main.removeClass().addClass('intro');
  });

  $button1.mouseleave(function () {
    $main.removeClass().addClass('outro');
  });  
});
```

With this solution, the '.outro' class will persist until you hover over the button again.

Combined with the style declarations above, this works exactly as you were hoping now and is easy to change later.

Again, here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chantastic/rGc7h/1/

Comment: wow many thanks! :D your answer was precise and well presented :) thanks man! though @Bic 's answer is also correct, wonder why it has -1 vote

Comment: Another user must have thought it didn't answer the question well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using jQuery to cycle the hover effects, why not just use CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/JtKFk/

HTML:

```
<p class="hoverable">hello world this is a test</p>
```

CSS:

```
.hoverable{
   -webkit-animation: recolorout .5s;
   color:red;  
}

.hoverable:hover{
   -webkit-animation: recolor .5s;
   color:blue;  
}

@-webkit-keyframes recolor {
   from{
       color:red;
   }
   to{
       color:blue;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes recolorout {
   from{
       color:blue;
   }

   to{
       color:red;
   }
}
```

Comment: I simply copied his code. If he wants to support other browsers, he can use the same CSS layout and add the rules for other browsers.

Comment: hey bro, i used webkit only because i'm using google chrome and this is for studying purpose only :D

Comment: i didn't use CSS only, cause i need a button to do the effect

Answer (score 1):

CODE:

```
$("#button1").mouseenter(function(){
$("#main").addClass("intro");
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $("#main").removeClass("intro");});
```

CSS:

```
#main {
color:red;
}
```

.intro {
    -webkit-animation: recolor .5s;
    color:blue;
  }
   @-webkit-keyframes recolor {
    from {
        color:red;
    }
    to {
        color:blue;
    }
  }
   .outro {
    -webkit-animation: recolor1 .5s;
    color:red;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes recolor1 {
    from {
        color:blue;
    }
    to {
         color:red;
    }
       }

http://jsfiddle.net/7eBCS/2/

Comment: +1 for pasting a shortened (as for now the third) copy of the OP's css ;)

Comment: @CodeToad hey bro i tried your fiddle but, when i hovered the button it does the .intro but it turns to red(#main) even if i didn't hovered out

Comment: yes, I need to fix that. let me look into please. see my other answer for css tricks

Answer (score 0):

if you reverse the order in the dom, you can do this:

```
 #button1  ~ p{
color:red;

}

#button1:hover  ~ p{
color:blue;

}

<button id="button1">button</button>
<p id="main">This should change the pharagraph within mouseenter/mouseleave</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7eBCS/3/

and there is this trick too:

```
 <p id="main">This should change the pharagraph within mouseenter/mouseleave</p>

 </button>




#button1 {
position:relative;

}

p{
 position:absolute;
top:200%;
width:400px;
 }


  #button1:hover > p{
   color:red;

  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7eBCS/4/

Comment: thanks man, i know about using the selector '~' but i want to learn how to do it in jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be using ids to change the styling on the elements. Try using classes instead. This will prevent the need to change any of the code based on whether or not the event has already been triggered.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button1").hover(function(){
        $("#main").addClass('intro').removeClass('outro').removeClass('main');
    },
    function(){
        $("#main").addClass('outro').removeClass('intro');;
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.main{
   color:red;
}

.intro{
   -webkit-animation: recolor .5s;
   color:blue;  
}

@-webkit-keyframes recolor {
    from{
       color:red;
    }
    to {
       color:blue;
    }
}

.outro{
   -webkit-animation: recolorout .5s;
   color:red;   
}

@-webkit-keyframes recolorout {
    from{
        color:blue;
    }
    to{
        color:red;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm thanks for the advice, but the problem with your code is when i hover the button it does the .intro but after executing .intro, it turns back to red(#main)

Comment: You can probably remove the main class from it to prevent this. I'll update the solution.

Comment: The main class is just a starter class, basically. You would remove it after the first hover, and wouldn't ever need to reapply it. I think teh1 might have a more elegant solution, though.

Comment: hmmm, your revision does not do .outro bro, maybe because you remove main?

Comment: If that is what you're going for, be sure to mark it as the answer :). Someone down voted it, but I'm not sure why since it is what you needed.

Comment: hey bro it's working but, what is #main for? yep after we polish it :D

Comment: #main is the id of the container for the text that will be changing a color. Initially, the main element also has a class of main, which has the 'default' styling. When you hover over the button the first time, the main class is removed. The id is retained, meaning that you can continue to use it in the selector for the mouseout half of the hover method.

Note, removeClass('main') is being called everytime you hover over the button, but since that class isn't there, it does nothing.

You could bind a one time hover event to remove the main class, so it isn't rexecuted everytime, if you want.

Comment: oh i get it, sorry for asking too many questions, but why put removeClass("outro") on the first one?

Comment: The class should get removed everytime you hover over the button. As with the main class, it technically won't do anything when the class isn't present (the first execution), but will function as needed afterwards.

Comment: many thanks man! i have studied your code indeed :D it works and really helpful! the hell why did someone clicked vote down on this post? :|